# Extract date from datetime column - SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Server Compact 4.0 version, and although it might seem a simple thing to find in google, the examples I've tried none of them work.

My column `signup_date` is a `DateTime` with a value `04-09-2016 09:05:00`.

What I've tried so far without success:

```
SELECT FORMAT(signup_date, 'Y-m-d') AS signup_date;
SELECT CONVERT(signup_date, GETDATE()) AS signup_date
SELECT CAST(data_registo, date) AS signup_date
```

I found that I could use `DATEPART` function, but that would force me to concat the values, is this the right path to follow? If so, how do I concat as Y-m-d?

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, signup_date)
```

Comment: Have you tried `convert(date, signup_date)`?

Comment: Yes, it retrieves the error: `The specified data type is not valid. [Data type (if known) = date]`

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the time portion, and just leave a DATE?

Comment: I want to retrieve the date from my datetime column. I manage to do this by c# code but I can't do it by SQL.

Comment: Is your return value a string, or a DATE type?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I just want to return the date, no matter if as a string format or as date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Compact has no date type.

If you don't want to see the time, convert the datetime value to a string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

(This has been tested and actually works against SQL Server Compact)

Comment: 120 brings back more than you need and then nvarchar(10) chops off what you don't need.

you can use select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 23) instead

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers seek to achieve same thing but the explanation to the codes is not enough

```
CONVERT(date, Date_Updated, 120)
```

this code does the conversion with mssql. The first item 'date' is the datatype to return. it could be 'datetime', 'varchar', etc.
The second item 'Date_Updated' is the name of the column to be converted.
the last item '120' is the date style to be returned. There are various styles and the code entered will determine the output. '120' represent YYYY-MM-DD.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

you were actually on track with the CAST function just a slight error in the syntax. In the CAST function, there needs to be 'as' i.e CAST(data_registo as date)

```
SELECT CAST(data_registo as date) AS signup_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The old fashioned way of doing this in SQL Server might work for your purposes:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, signup_date), 0)
```

The `datediff()` gets the number of days (as an integer) since time 0.  The `dateadd()` adds this number back.

If you don't like `0` as a date, you can put any valid date in its place:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, '2000-01-01', signup_date), '2000-01-01')
```

EDIT:

If you simply don't want to see the time, convert the date to a string:

```
select convert(nvarchar(10), signup_date, 120)
```

(I recommend the YYYY-MM-DD format, but others are [available](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450(v=sql.110).aspx).)

Comment: The time is still returned.

Comment: Doesn't work your edit either. Error: `The specified data type is not valid. [Data type (if known) = varchar]`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and many other solutions. I wanted a generic solution that would work with any LCID. My solution is a bit of convoluted code, but it works perfectly for me. It's a booking system where I needed to find out who was arriving on a particular date. `ArriveDate` is the column, `d` is the DATE I want.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, 
ArriveDate), 0)=' " & Format(d, "yyyy-MM-dd") & " ' "
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return only date value in original datetime type. So you can do any comparison using the output

```
SELECT  convert(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 120))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the Question today,  a bit late I know :)  but maybe this will help..,

```
select  convert(date,(convert(varchar(20),'04-09-2016 09:05:00')))
```

Answer (score 0):

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 1) = 09/25/19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 2) = 19.09.25

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 3) = 25/09/19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 4) = 25.09.19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 5) = 25-09-19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 6) = 25 Sep 19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 7) = Sep 25, 19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 10) = 09-25-19

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 11) = 19/09/25

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 12) = 190925

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 23) = 2019-09-25

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 101) = 09/25/2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 102) = 2019.09.25

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 103) =  25/09/2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 104) = 25.09.2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 105) = 25-09-2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 106) = 25 Sep 2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 107) = Sep 25, 2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 110) = 09-25-2019

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 111) = 2019/09/25

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 112) = 20190925

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 8) =  13:48:36

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 14) = 13:49:48:713

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 24) = 13:49:57

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 108) = 13:50:07

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 114) = 13:50:14:490

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 0) = Sep 25 2019  1:50PM

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 9) =  Sep 25 2019  1:50:31:813PM

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 13) = 25 Sep 2019 13:50:39:307

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 20) = 2019-09-25 13:50:49

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 21) = 2019-09-25 13:50:58.923

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 22) = 09/25/19  1:51:07 PM

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 25) = 2019-09-25 13:51:14.473

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 100) = Sep 25 2019  1:51PM

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 109) = Sep 25 2019  1:51:32:227PM

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 113) = 25 Sep 2019 13:51:38:740

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 120)  = 2019-09-25 13:51:50

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 121) = 2019-09-25 13:51:57.153

select convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 126) = 2019-09-25T13:52:03.627

Answer (score 0):

Use this, i had the same problem

```
SELECT CAST(data_registo as date) AS "signup_date"
```

Comment: Did you've tested that? SQL Server CE does not list such datatype [in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/ff801931(v=vs.100)) as posted above.

Answer (score -1):

To get a string value, use `CONVERT`

```
select convert(varchar(10), signup_date, 11)
```

Check here for various formats:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

To get a DATE, and just strip out the time, do this

```
Select Cast (signup_date as DATE)
```

Comment: None of the solutions work. The error: `The specified data type is not valid. [Data type (if known) = DATE]`